# How to change the starting ConstraintSet in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have more than one `ConstraintSet`s in a `MotionLayout` and one of them is the default starting point.

How can I set one of the other `ConstraintSet`s to be the starting point?

Answer (score 2):

The default starting ConstraintSet is the constraintSetStart="@id/xxx" of the first (from the top)  in the MotionScene.